# ¿Por que éste método solo me muestra un objeto en la vista y en el navegador todos?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Mi problema es que sólo me muestra el primer objeto del array json pero en la consola del navegador salen todos.

Como podría mostrar todos esos elementos que me retorna el for en texto?

```
<div id="success">
<div id="artistName"></div>

</div>
<script>
  $.ajax({ 
      type : 'POST', 
      url : 'http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/', 
      data :'method=artist.gettopalbums&'+'artist=cooldplay&'+api_key=57ee3318536b23ee81d6b27e36997cde&' + 'format=json',
      dataType : 'jsonp', 
      success : function(data) {
          for( var i=0 in data.topalbums.album) {
              $('#success #artistName').html(data.topalbums.album[i].name);
          } 
      }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Cuidado con la inyección de código. append agrega código html y el name podría tener caracteres inválidos (en especial si fueron cargados en la base de datos por un usuario). Es preferible armar un span dentro del append. Así `$("#success").append($("<span>").text(data.topalbums.album[i].name)).append($("<br>"));`. Ver [https://jsfiddle.net/EmilioPlatzer/6bvn3r3s/1/]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo que estas haciendo en el `for` es sustituir el código `html` que hay en los `<div>` cada ciclo del `for`, por ende solo te imprime el último valor. Para que imprima todos, lo podrías hacer de la siguiente manera.

```
var str = "";
for( var i=0 in data.topalbums.album)
    str += data.topalbums.album[i].name+"<br>";
$('#success').html(str);
```

o también puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera y te ahorras líneas de código.

```
for( var i=0 in data.topalbums.album)
    $('#success').append(data.topalbums.album[i].name+"<br>");
```

Lo que hace `.append()` es que te agrega, al contrario de `.html()` que te sustituye.

Comment: Genial gracias, ahora si entendi porque no mostraba todos

Answer (score 1):

Esto podria ayudarte:

```
$.ajax({ 
          type : 'POST', 
          url : 'http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/', 
          data :'method=artist.gettopalbums&'+'artist=cooldplay&'+api_key=57ee3318536b23ee81d6b27e36997cde&' + 'format=json',
          dataType : 'jsonp', 
          success : function(data) {
              var name = data.topalbums.album[i].name;

              for( var i=0 in data.topalbums.album) {
                   $('#success').append("<div>"+name+"</div>");
              } 
          }
    });
```